# jquery problem with .children() and .fadeOut()

Tags: jquery

I want to get all the children of a div, fade them out, and then insert some text in the div. I'm using a callback function in fadeOut() so the animation is smooth:

```
var foo = $(this).parents('.foo').eq(0);
foo.children().fadeOut(300,function() {
  foo.prepend('some text');
});
```

Problem is that fadeOut seems to be firing on *each* of the children in sequence, rather than all at once - there are three children, so the callback function fires for each of them, resulting in three instances of the inserted text. I could just wrap all the children in a div and fade that out, but I'd like to avoid adding more markup if I can. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var foo = $(this).parents('.foo').eq(0);
foo.fadeOut(300,function() {//fade out foo
  foo
     .children().hide().end()//set display none to foo's children
     .prepend('some text').show();//prepend text to foo and show it (but children have display none)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `children()` and call it on `foo` directly.

Alternatively, in the callback...

```
function() {
   if ($(this).siblings(':animated').length) {
      return;
   }
   // What you need to do once only :)
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/tJvb6/).